# What's wrong with boost::posix_time::time_duration::total_seconds?

Tags: c++, boost

Consider this piece of code (compiled with VS2015, using boost 1.60:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_duration.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    uint64_t val = static_cast<uint64_t>( 5000000000 * 1000000 );
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    boost::posix_time::time_duration the = boost::posix_time::microseconds( val );
    std::cout << the << std::endl;
    auto res3 = the.total_seconds();
    std::cout << res3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
5000000000000000
1388888:53:20
705032704
```

Two first lines are OK. However, last line should report 5000000000 (5000000000000000 microseconds is 5000000000 seconds....which is exactly (1388888*3600+53*60+20)).

Where does this `705032704` comes from??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a stupid cast issue in boost:

```
sec_type total_seconds() const
{
  return static_cast<sec_type>(ticks() / ticks_per_second());
}
```

`ticks()` and `ticks_per_second()` both return `int64_t`. `(ticks() / ticks_per_second())` is evaluated to `5000000000`. But, as `boost::posix_time::time_duration::sec_type` is `int32_t`...the static_cast transforms `5000000000` (out of `int32_t` range...max value being `4294967295`) into `705032704` (`=5000000000-4294967295-1`)).

Comment: Time to submit a bug report! :)

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) explicitly says the return type is `long`. Should've been the first place you looked.

Comment: @Borgleader There already is one: [Bug 3109](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3109).

Comment: @sleeptightpupper *Opened 7 years ago. Last modified 4 years ago* Oh wow... Maybe a new one is a good idea :P

Comment: @Borgleader Here are more: [one](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2819), [two](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3487). Instead of submitting duplicate bug reports I would turn on `-Wsign-conversion` and find more productive ways of working around the problem.